# Unable to get the elements of an iframe using phantomJS

Tags: node.js, iframe, phantomjs, nightmare

I am searching for a way to get the control on the elements inside a document. The problem is, the document is attached to an iFrame.

Here's an example:

```
    .goto('https://wirecard-sandbox-engine.thesolution.com/engine/hpp/')    

    .use(iframe.withFrameName('wc', function (nightmare) {
    nightmare
            .type('#account_number', accountNumber)
       .screenshot(resultfolder + '\\06-Card-Number.png')
       .type('#card_security_code', testData.securityCode)
       .selectIndex('#expiration_month_list', 1)
       .selectIndex('#expiration_year_list', 4)
       .click('span[id="hpp-form-submit"]')
}))
```

What I am trying to do above is:

- Getting the iFrame with the Url.
- Using this to get the control on every element in iFrame.

Comment: Are you sure that you're using PhantomJS? The newest nightmare version uses Electron.

Answer (score 2):

I encountered a similar issue. For one reason or another (Windows? Outdated?) the package `nightmare-iframe` was not working for me.

So I did this using pure DOM, which would transcribe for you:

```
var info = {
    "account": account_number,
    "security": testData.security_code;
};

nightmare.wait( () => {
    /* Return true when the iframe is loaded */
    var iframe = document.querySelector("iframe[name='wc']");

    if (!iframe) {
        return false;
    }

    var iframeDocument = iframe.contentDocument || iframe.contentWindow.document;

    return iframeDocument.querySelector("#account_number") != null;
}).evaluate( (info) => {
    var iframe = document.querySelector("iframe[name='wc']");
    var iframeDocument = iframe.contentDocument || iframe.contentWindow.document;

    iframeDocument.querySelector("#account_number").value = info.account;
    iframeDocument.querySelector("#card_security_code").value = info.security;
    //also use DOM to set proper date
    ...

    iframeDocument.querySelector("span#hpp-form-submit").click();
}, info).then( () => {
    console.log("submit done!");
}).catch((error) => {
    console.error("Error in iframe magic", error);
});
```

This only works of course if the iframe is in the same domain as the main page and [same-origin](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Security/Same-origin_policy) is allowed for the iframe. My use case was logging into paypal from a merchant's page.

For iframes with different origin, `nightmare-iframe` would be the package to use but then an error is needed to see what's the problem.